# How to send data to DataTables (for add row)

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have a php file that retrieves information from the database (add.php)

I would like this information to be added to my table (DataTables)

So I try to do that (I deliberately simplified)

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).on("click", "#add", function(){
  $.post("/ajax/add.php", {info: number}).done(function(data){
    $('#fileTable').DataTable().row.add(data).draw();
  });
});
```

In my add.php file, I have my request that gives me this information:

```
$request = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM product WHERE ...');
$request->execute();
$info = $request->fetch();
```

The request works is it returns to me:

```
$a = $info['a']
$b = $info['b']
$c = $info['c']
$d = $info['d']
```

I would like to return his information in order to add them to the table, so I tried several things (always in my add.php file):

```
echo "[$a, $b, $c, $d]";
echo "{0: $a, 1: $b, 2: $c, 3: $d}";
```

It does not work... How to do ?

Comment: In php variables why are there spaces after `$`?

Comment: What is the database connection you are using? And what exactly does the returned `data` contain?

Comment: @mega6382 sorry it's not normal, I modify my post

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
header("Content-type:application/json");
$request = $ bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM product WHERE ...');
$request->execute();
$info = $request->fetch();

echo json_encode($info)
```

Comment: It works almost but how to select the data I send in json because I have an error message on datatables **DataTables warning: table id=fileTable - Requested unknown parameter '3' for row 6, column 3. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4**

Comment: @Rocstar This means there is discrepancy between the number of elements in your array and the number of columns in your table.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at [datatables docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()), it seems that the `add()` function should take a JSON object.

I'm not certain what you are passing to it.

You may need to do this:

```
var table = $('#fileTable');
table.row.add(JSON.stringify(data)).draw();
```

Failing that, `console.log(data)` and this will help you understand what you are currently passing to the `add()` function

Comment: Thank you but what should data look like? like this: [1,2,3,4]?

Comment: @Rocstar, that depends on how your table is initialised. If it is a pure dom `<table>` it should be an array of strings, or an array of array of strings; if your table is based on a JSON source or array of objects `data` should have that structure as well.

Comment: JSON.stringify() can handle lots of different types of variable. What does data look like at the moment?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify